# Crear un formulario con wordpress avanzado

Tags: wordpress

como puedo crear un formulario de wordpress que permita que el usuario se registre con varios roles dependiendo del caso. Tengo los roles configurados que son: persona juridica, natural y distribuidor. Pero no encuentro un plugin que me lea estos roles al momento de registrarse.Ademas tengo linkadas las paginas para que el usuario elija el tipo de cliente que será, solo me falta eso, que el usuario pueda registrarse como, persona juridica, natural o distribuidor. Estaría agradecido con su ayuda ya que llevo días solucionando esto.

Comment: fijate si este te sirve https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-roles/

Comment: Gracias >) pero necesito es crear un formulario semi avanzado, nombre, apellido email password, etc, pero que ese furmulario me indique para que tipo de usuario es, si es para persona natura o persona juridica o distribuidor

Comment: Se me ocurre que con contact 7 form puedes crear el formulario a mano y asignarle tú los roles manualmente cuando hayas verificado que el usuario cumple los requisitos para pertenecer a ese rol. Entiende que por seguridad puedes asignar el rol por defecto cuando el usuario se registra, pero no puedes permitir que el propio usuario se asigne el rol así mismo.

Comment: pero el rol que le voy a dar es un rol de usuario normal, o customer, como lo pone por defecto woocomerce. El usuario se va a registrar pero quedara registrado como persona natural o juridica dependiendo el que elija al momento de registrarse. Voy a intentarlo con contact form